# Launch a custom screensaver + lock machine

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application I'd like to accomplish 2 things when a user wants to take a break and clicks a log out button.

1. Lock the machine
2. Launch a custom screen saver that would show the time the user is logged out.

I managed to do the lock easily by:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern void LockWorkStation();
```

I found a [tutorial](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/screensaver/screensaver.html) on how to make a custom screen saver. I downloaded the sample code and it worked fine. But when I added the **LockWorkStation();** line it killed the screen saver.

Can you help me with this or suggest a workaround?

**EDIT**

This screen saver from tutorial is just w WinForm. Should I somehow install it to the system? Is it possible form my application level?

Answer (score 2):

The solution most likely is the following:

1. Lock the workstation
2. Show the screensaver

For the second step, the following is important:

You application is simply a program showing a window. As such any windows it tries to show are not shown to the user when the workstation is locked.
Your window will only be shown when you [register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282456/how-to-install-screensaver-programmatically) your program as a real screensaver, set it as the current screensaver and than start it, for example using the [`SC_SCREENSAVE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267728/launch-system-screensaver-from-c-sharp-windows-form) message.

Comment: It doesn't work. The screen saver just blinks and than is replaced with log in screen. LockWorkStation();
                ScreenSaverForm screensaver = new ScreenSaverForm(screen.Bounds);
                screensaver.Show(); I guess it may be because this screen saver is just a WinForm. Is it possible to somehow 'install' it from my application level?

Comment: @gisek: Your assumption is most likely correct. Please check my updated answer.