# how to create setup project to install scr file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-screensaver

I want to implement **(exe or msi)** to install screen saver **(scr)** file on any machine.
Please guide how to implement ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to install screensaver programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282456/how-to-install-screensaver-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Setup package with Visual Studio, set the output path to `X:\Windows\` (Where X is the system drive) and probably running some command line to register the screensaver with Windows.

Also check out; http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353 (Create Setup package)

Probably this one will help you even more; [how to install screensaver programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282456/how-to-install-screensaver-programmatically)